# How to make sure a stem cell culture is cancer free?

Tags: cancer, stem-cells

Say I take a blood sample from an adult, extract the white cells and apply to them the process described in <[this article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/behindtheheadlines/news/2014-01-30-breakthrough-in-stem-cell-creation-using-acid-bath/)>. Assuming this actually turns the adult white cells into stem cells, which I then transfer to a culture in order to grow an arbitrary quantity, how can I make sure in the end this culture is free of cancer stem cells? Is there a last step that can be applied which would eliminate any potential CSCs leaving only healthy cells in the culture?

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt that this differentiation between these cells is possible. Stem cells are not expressing very much surface markers and are relative inconspicuous. So you can only cultivate them and look for the outcome.

Comment: HAT media additives?

Comment: The moethod described in this paper has never been reproduced outside the Riken Institute (which claimed to have to developed the method). The papers describing it have since then been retracted due to scientific misconduct (falsified figures, which of course only have been wrongly put in there and so on) which caused a major scandal.

Answer (score 3):

It would not be possible to differentiate CSC from normal population non-invasively and select them out. You may do a single cell expression analysis to say if a CSC is present in a population or not but there is no magic bullet method for eliminating them. Also there are several oncogenes and some of them are also required for usual stem cell function. HAT kind of methods will not be able to eliminate potential cancer cells. Also, usual cancer chemotherapeutic drugs also affect other actively growing cell.

Bottomline: Not possible with the current level of knowledge and technology.